How to schedule notification to repeat every week starting from specific date in expo?
There is an API to schedule a local notification weekly but I can't find a way to make it start on a specific date like: a notification that repeat weekly starting from 1 July.

Try to use  this trigger CalendarNotificationTrigger: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/?redirected#calendarnotificationtrigger to schedule notification on specific date/month and year once. When you catch this specific notification on 1st July - will schedule weekly notification

@DmitriyS But what if it fails to be caught in case the app is killed for instance?
